# Move left-aligned text to the right

Tags: align

I'm trying to align a document heading (myName, myPhone, myMail) which I want to show on the right. For instance,

```
                                                        myName
                                                        myPhone
                                                        myMail
```

I've tried something like this, but it does not seem to work

```
\hspace{12cm} myName \newline
\hspace{12cm} myPhone \newline
\hspace{12cm} myMail
```

I would be grateful to receive some helpful advice. Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  For future reference, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the block of 3 lines aligned on left but pushed to right, use

```
\begin{flushright}
  \begin{tabular}{l@{}}
    myName\\myPhone\\myMail
  \end{tabular}
\end{flushright}
```

or only `flushright` to push everything to right.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{flushright}
  \begin{tabular}{l@{}}
    myName\\myPhone\\myMail
\end{tabular}
\end{flushright}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{flushright}
%  \begin{tabular}{l}
    myName\\myPhone\\myMail
%\end{tabular}
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

[image]